# How to transfer file (PDF) from imac to iphone when no internet

Tags: software-recommendation, imac, file-transfer

Does anyone know of any software that will allow me to send a pdf from my iMac to iPhone 5 when I have no internet please?

Answer (score 1):

You could always set up a local network on your mac. Then you can use Dysoft's Download Manager, it has a buit-in ftp/http server you can locally connect to.

It also supports transferring files through iTunes, using the Apps tab (Device > Apps > Bottom of the page: "file transfer").

There are probably a lot of other apps that can do this, but I use this one and never had any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could transfer it through iTunes, add it to the iBooks tab..sync..

Then you can open it through the iBooks app on your iPhone